# How to add class attribute to ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have model:

```
class TestPolja(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Test polja'

        integerPolje1 = models.IntegerField('integerPolje1')
        charPolje1 = models.CharField('charPolje1',max_length = 1024)
        bigint1 = models.BigIntegerField('bigint1',default = 67573737)
        date = models.DateField('date')
```

and modelForm:

```
class TestPoljaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestPolja
```

How to change `TestPoljaForm` to add `class` attribute to `<input>` tag?

How to add widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in `__init__` form method:

```
class TestPoljaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestPolja

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestPoljaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # for example change class for integerPolje1
        self.fields['integerPolje1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'SOMECLASS'

        # you can iterate all fields here
        for fname, f in self.fields.items():
            f.widget.attrs['class'] = 'SOMECLASS'
```

Comment: And for each field i must iterate trough all fields and add widget?

Answer (score 3):

```
class TestPoljaForm(ModelForm):
    integerPolje1 =  forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myclass'}))

    class Meta:
        model = TestPolja
```

Comment: I would prefer this method.

Comment: This is ok too, but i want to set the same class name to all fields.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to add classes in `dict` notation. I tried  `attrs=dict(class='my_class')` but this obviously did not work, since Django (i.e. Python) was expecting a class declaration after `class`